# Image resources in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a simple question .

Supposedly I have an image placed as a header in my android application .

My cellphone resolution is for example (480 X 800 -HDPI)

So I would ask my designer to make a header image for me , which has its X cordinate as large as 480 , so that it completely fits the screen horizontally .

What I dont understand is that , what would happen if my application is executed on a cellphone which has its X coordinate different then 480 ?

Because there are tons of devices out there , would I have to ask my designer to make a header image for me , for every possible horizontal width ?

I would have so many folders like 
drawable-hdpi-800x500
drawable-hdpi-800x550
drawable-hdpi-700x555

This would ofcourse be a mess for me and my designer , and I believe there is something I am missing .

Please aid me .

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify the size in your xml layout file using DP (DIP: Density Independent Pixels) instead of Pixels, you can also use wrap_content and match_parent.

For more info,
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html